Trapped in non-stop Memtest86+ v7
I performed a restart via the terminal yesterday. Ever since then, the laptop is trapped in Memtest86+ v7 running all night and never gets to continue booting (completed 7 passes). The Esc key simply restarts the boring test again.
Using 24.04 with Intel Ultra 5 processor. What's the workaround to safely exit this and resume booting?

The memtest program runs until told to exit; on exit it reboots the machine.   If you've made memtest the default option in grub (in error), you need to undo that change and return the default to booting the system. You didn't specify what 24.04 (Server? Desktop?), but reboot & select another option at grub (rather than memtest if its your default)... If you reduced the timeout you'll need to be quick (be faster than whatever time you allowed) or make change from live media. Your issue is likely the result of your last change to grub configuration.

Using Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS. That's exactly my question, how do I change the default to booting?
